# Datatrigger not updating passwordbox colour when characters are entered

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Hie.

So I have a password box.
What I basically am trying to do is to get it's border colour to change to Red if it's empty and change to white if it's not.
A simple mechanism just to inform the user which field they left blank on the sign up form.

After a bit of research I put together this code.

```
<Window.Resources>
    <conv:rules x:Key="isNullConverter"/>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type PasswordBox}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Password, ValidatesOnDataErrors=False, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Converter={StaticResource isNullConverter}}" Value="False">
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="White"/>
            </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Password, ValidatesOnDataErrors=False, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Converter={StaticResource isNullConverter}}" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Red"/>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
```

'conv' is set to reference 'rules' namespace.

'rules' is the class where I put the below code.

```
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Globalization;

namespace Masca
{
    public class rules : IValueConverter, INotifyPropertyChanged, IDataErrorInfo
    {

    private string something;

    public string Password
    {
        get
        {
            return something;
        }

        set
        {
            if (something!= value)
            {
                something = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("Password");
            }
        }
    }


    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value == null)
        {
            value = false;
        }
        if (value != null)
        {
            value = true;
        }
        return value;
    }

    private void RaisePropertyChanged(string prop)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged == null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop));
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public string Error
    {
        get { return null; }
    }
```

Every time I run the program though, There is always a red border around the password box, even after I've typed something. Shouldn't the DataTrigger update the boundary to white? Or am I missing something?

Comment: I think your problem is that, 'Password' is not a dependency property of a PasswordBox. The control doesnt expose the property because of security

Answer (score 0):

"What I basically am trying to do is to get it's border colour to change to Red if it's empty and change to white if it's not."

If this is your problem, then simply have the trigger activate off of the `Text` property of the `TextBox`. If it is `""`, then the `BorderBrush` is red; otherwise `White`. FYI, you only need one trigger for this, not two. Set the "normal" default color as a property on the control, then a trigger for if `Text` is `""`:

`<Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="White">`

and

`<Trigger Property="Text" Value="">
    <Setter Property=BorderBrush" Value="Red"/>
</Trigger>`

P.S. You may want to ensure that the `TextBox` has received focus at least once before you color the border Red